# Using WSS 3.0 console application on SharePoint 2013

Tags: .net, sharepoint

We have a console application which is used to administer WSS 3.0 sites.
The application uses the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly, which in WSS 3.0 is of version 12.0.0.0

Now, we want to use the same console application on SharePoint 2013, without having to rebuild a new one for that specific version.
Since SharePoint 2013 comes with version 15.0.0.0 of the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly, I have created an application configuration file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SharePoint"
                           publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c"
                           culture="neutral"
     />
         <!-- Redirecting to version 15.0.0.0 of the assembly. -->
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0"
                          newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It doesn't work however, binding fails. Any ideas why?

I see the following in the binding logs:

```
** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2013-07-15 @ 11:28:53) **

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\fredrikg\Desktop\Customer\Bin\UseMicrosoftSharePoint.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = INFOWEAVER\fredrikg
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/fredrikg/Desktop/Customer/Bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : UseMicrosoftSharePoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\fredrikg\Desktop\Customer\Bin\UseMicrosoftSharePoint.exe.Config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 12.0.0.0 redirected to 15.0.0.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fredrikg/Desktop/Customer/Bin/Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fredrikg/Desktop/Customer/Bin/Microsoft.SharePoint/Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fredrikg/Desktop/Customer/Bin/Microsoft.SharePoint.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fredrikg/Desktop/Customer/Bin/Microsoft.SharePoint/Microsoft.SharePoint.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
LOG: Attempting to install assembly using Windows Installer.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
```

Comment: Are you running the console application on the SP2013 server?

Comment: Yes, and I realized the problem. Since SP2013 is using .NET 4.5, all its assemblies are installed in the (new) .NET 4 GAC. And my console application is using .NET 3.5, and will use the old GAC. Therefore, looking up will fail. Building my console application with .NET 4.5 fixes this. But now I have to handle 2 versions of the application, since I don't want to require my clients to use .NET 4.0...